# How to define Enum in JSON schema?

Tags: java, json, rest

I declared `Enum` in `JSON` schema as below. I have generated artifacts using schema without any issues.

Currently, I am working on validation part using `com.github.fge.jsonschema.* api`.
But during validation, the API is not validating when i submit `JSON` request without `sourceType`  element . Need help to resolve the validation error.

*Note*: Schema version is V4

**Enum declaration**

Main Schema

```
    {
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "title": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "description": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "requestHeader": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/RequestHeader.json#/definitions/requestHeader"
        },
        "sourceType": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/sourceType"
        },
        "billingSystem": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/billingSystem"
        },
        "siteId": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/siteId"
        },
        "ocnValue": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/ocnValue"
        },
        "raoValue": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/raoValue"
        },
        "tn": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/tn"
        },
        "actionCode": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/actionCode"
        },
        "serviceClass": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/serviceClass"
        },
        "bnsCode": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/bnsCode"
        },
        "privacyIndicator": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/privacyIndicator"
        },
        "customerName": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/customerName"
        },
        "workOrderNumber": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/workOrderNumber"
        },
        "accountNumber": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/accountNumber"
        },
        "portInFlag": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/portInFlag"
        },
        "sendDate": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/sendDate"
        },
        "transferFromAccountNumber": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/transferFromAccountNumber"
        },
        "transferToAccountNumber": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/transferToAccountNumber"
        },
        "comments": {
            "$ref": "resource:/json/LcBase.json#/definitions/lcBase/properties/comments"
        }
    }
}
```

SubSchema

```
{
    "definitions": {
        "lcBase": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "transactionId": {
                    "type": "integer",
                    "minLength": 0,
                    "maxLength": 15
                },
                "sourceType": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": [
                        "abc",
                        "xyz"
                    ]
                },......
```

---

### Java Validator code

```
                JsonNode schemaNode = JsonLoader.fromResource(getResource(reqType)); // Root Node .Class
            JsonNode data = JsonLoader.fromString(jsonString);
            JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.byDefault();
            JsonSchema schema = factory.getJsonSchema(schemaNode);
            report = schema.validate(data);
            if (report != null) {
                Iterator<ProcessingMessage> iter = report.iterator();
                while (iter.hasNext()) {
                    ProcessingMessage pm = iter.next();
                    stringBuilder.append(pm.getMessage()).append(",\n");
                }
                result = report.isSuccess();
            }
```

Comment: json does not know enums. Your "enum" is just an array

Comment: ok. Is there a way to validate Enum/Array using json schema validator as i wanted to automate server side validation instead manual.

Comment: Can you share your entire schema with us? Presumably, it indicates that "sourceType" is mandatory. What is the output when you plug the schema and sample data into your validator's provided app http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/?

Comment: Please edit your question. Do not add comments. The code is basically unreadable. Put that information in your question and delete the comments. Put everything in one place. Make it easy for people to help you.